# Force an input box to start with a character

Tags: php, html, text, input, textbox

I've searched quite a bit for this, but to no avail. I'm trying to make my input box start with a "#". It cannot just be a `<span>#</span>`, it needs to be in the input box itself. Is there no way of doing this?

Comment: could you just append it afterward? is this for a form `POST`?

Comment: you mean `value="#"` ?

Comment: `<input type="text" value="#">`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this on the client side with a bit of javascript

```
function addHash(elem) {
  var val = elem.value;
  if(!val.match(/^#/)) {
    elem.value = "#" + val;
  }
}
```

and the HTML

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="addHash(this)"/>
```

Every time the user enters a character into the textbox, addHash would check if the first character is a hash, and if it isn't, then adds the hash mark.

Comment: Mike's solution is good for checking anything posted to the server. My solution will not allow the user to delete the #, however. Unless they have javascript disabled or are posting to the server not using the form (which is possible), the # will always be at the front of the input box.

Comment: @Robbert's solution is a good one for aesthetic purposes. His comment above further illustrates the point that you should _very_ seldom trust data sent from the client. To use it, you definitely need to check that a) a browser is being used and b) said browser has JS enabled. Even with both of those, you should still do quick checks server-side

Comment: These two solutions work very well on a normal computer, however, I've found that on a mobile device, you can still delete the hash. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check this server-side, since users can and probably will erase it:

```
function prependHash($string) {
  if(substr($string, 0, 1) === "#") { return $string }
  else return "#" . $string;
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="someInput" value="#">
```

Relevant PHP:

```
//just in case they erase the hash:
$hashedValue = prependHash($_POST['someInput']);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything. You're right about the # deletion bug though.

Comment: If the # is already there, it shouldn't change anything. If it's not (because a user deleted it), this would simply prepend it to the string.